# Power BI Report Builder Dynamic Tables based on column

Tags: sql, ssrs-2012, powerbi-paginated-reports

I have a table that contains the columns name age and Dept. I am new to report builder and wanted to know if there is a way possible to create dynamic tables based on distinct departments in the base table

Below is the base data

[image]

and this is how I want this to be represented in SSRS dynamically based on distinct items in the Dept. column

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just add a Row Group to your table that grouped by `Dept`.

If you click the existing table you should see one of more row groups in the groups panel below the main design window. There might be just a single "Details" row group. Right click the row group and add a parent group, select `Dept` as the column to group by and that's it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out.
Can use a list and add the desired table in there and then add in a group for the column required in the Group properties of the row